# Why isn't my nested while loop generating desired output?

Tags: php

Last question wasn't received well so I've done more reading and came up with a simple php program that accepts user input for number of rows and columns. A table is generated using nested while loop and I do understand that a 'For' loop is more suited for this and got it working using one. Trying to learn and get better so I want to figure this one out too. I'm getting one row only and no columns. I also want the iteration to produce rows and columns that appear like the example. Kind of frustrated the for loop was much easier to finally figure out.

```
W,row1,col1; W,row1,col2; W,row1,col3
W,row2,col1; W,row2,col2; W,row2,col3 etc...
```

php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['rows'])) { 



$r = 1;
$c = 1;
$rows = 5;
$cols = 6;
while ($r <= $rows) {
        echo '<tr>';
        while($c <= $cols) {
            echo '<td>W, '.'row' .$r.',col'.$c.';</td>';
            $c++;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $r++;
    }   

    ?>
```

Comment: you have nothing keeping track of how many loop iterations you have done. Think about what the code is doing and sound it out in words. ```$rows``` is always the same number, you need to have something that decrements ```$rows``` (and ```$cols``` of course) on each iteration of the loop so that eventually it will no longer be >=1. You are also missing a semi-colon on ```$count++```. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to change the evaluation condition to ($rows != 0) and cols the same. And of course keep a counter for rows....thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never changing the variables that you're testing in the `while` conditions, so the loops are infinite. You need to decrement the variables each time.

And you need to re-initialize `$cols` before each inner loop. Otherwise, the end condition will already be met after the first iteration of the outer loop.

```
$count = 1;
$rows = $_REQUEST['rows'];

//while loop to create table

while ($rows-- >= 1) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $cols = $_REQUEST['cols'];
    while ($cols-- >= 1) {
        echo '<td>W,row1,col1;</td>';
        $count++
    }
    echo '</tr>';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['rows'])) { 

//Create counters

    $count = 1;
    $rows = $_REQUEST['rows'];
    $cols = $_REQUEST['cols'];

    //for loop to create table

    for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++){
        echo '<tr>';
        for($j=1;$j<=$cols;$j++){
            echo '<td>W,'.'row'.$i.',col'.$j.';</td>';        
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working with the for loop above with the output formatted correctly. Will make changes to the while loop. Been staring at this for nearly 3 hours and missed the semi colon and should have used the ($rows != 0). I'm sure with the comments here I'll figure it out. Never hurts to get another set of eyes on it.